# How to install correctly Zeppeling and load PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

First, download and unzip .tgz

```
tar xvf zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all.tgz
```

Second, modify variables home,

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Adding

`export SPARK_HOME="/home/miguel/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/"`

Third, Lunch Zeppeling on cmd

```
bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

Fourth, Try to execute pyspark

```
%pyspark
print("Hello")
```

And I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobProgressListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.setupListeners(SparkInterpreter.java:170)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:148)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:843)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.getSparkInterpreter(PySparkInterpreter.java:565)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.createGatewayServerAndStartScript(PySparkInterpreter.java:209)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:162)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

zeppelin 0.7.3 don't support spark 2.3. spark 2.3 is supported by zeppelin 0.8 which will be released soon

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know

Comment: I thought Zeppelin use any Spark version in its $SPARK_HOME regardless of its native Spark version which it was shipped with?

Comment: Got it: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/%3Cbb1f44a0067c42ec9d8d632c99d9a317@git.apache.org%3E

Comment: Weird. Amazon's EMR is using Zeppelin 0.7.3 with Spark version 2.3.2.